# Image animation in css and html

Tags: html, css

I am making a website where i need some help with animation.

I have a div which is something like this:

```
<div id="header">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<img src="....Image">

</div>
```

The image should not be shown at first - but when a user click this header, it should drop down as an animation from the top.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: it drops & then , header expands, content is pushed down, how big is that image .... :) can you clarify

Comment: click this header ?!! is your header a button ? :'D

Answer (score 0):

A vague question gets a vague answer :) But take a look at http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ where you can get a nice effect like that. I would only include the animation I'd use from the CSS file. You have to trigger this with JavaSript on click, then add a class to the text that triggers the animation.

Comment: Hello @tony.gustafsson. I am quite new to StackOverFlow. Please explain how i can improve my questions, so i know in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

CSS

```
#header {
  position: relative;
}

#header img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -150px; <!-- Your Image height + some -->
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

#header.toggled img {
  top: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

JS(jQuery)

```
$('#header').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPaqzP